# USB over wireless

Tags: usb, wifi-direct

this is a more HW question. I was wondering, is someone aware of a device which enables to connect a USB device to a PC over WiFi?

The idea is to plug USB device into a transmitter and have a receiver at the PC side. The data would be transferred wirelessy.

I have learned that the key word for this type of devices is WUSB. However, I am failing to find a successfully stories behind using some of these, as well as a good device.

Does someone have an experience?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen any USB hubs that can transmit over Wi-Fi. But there are several Wireless Hubs available. Like these

http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/131933064085?lpid=82&chn=ps&ul_noapp=true

https://jet.com/product/detail/49089829a0c7458d9d30c1ec308febef?jcmp=pla:ggl:gen_electronics_a1:networking_bridges_routers_wireless_access_points_a1_other:na:PLA_348772140_24231289500_pla-177033586620:na:na:na:2&code=PLA15&ds_c=gen_electronics_a1&ds_cid=&ds_ag=networking_bridges_routers_wireless_access_points_a1_other&product_id=49089829a0c7458d9d30c1ec308febef&product_partition_id=177033586620&gclid=CJTyuaXNjM8CFYQkgQodOLAIkA&gclsrc=aw.ds

They have an adapter you plug into the PC and the hub works just like it would if it were wired.

Why do you need it to transmit over Wi-Fi specifically?

Comment: I would simply like to avoid cables between two devices. It is a design issue :).

Thank you for the links. I will check them and report here if I succeed in the intention.

Comment: I would be also interested in WUSB solutions for my USB Device wanted to be connected without USB CALBE. Any advices and recommendations this long time ago ?